# Change date format taken from an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So I'm going through an API and receiving dates in the following format: 
`2017-03-23` but I want it to be displayed like this: `3/23/2017`. What's the best way to go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: What API are you talking about? Does the API have a formatter for the date you're getting?

Answer (score 2):

For a quick fix,

```js
var date = '2017-03-23';
date = date.split('-').map(e => e[0] == '0' ? e.slice(1) : e);
date = date[1] + '/' + date[2] + '/' + date[0];

console.log(date)
```

But I recommend using a date library like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to insure stability and full compatibility

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about parsing the date. I just used string manipulation here, no object nor format involved. Of course, if the date is not to be displayed, moment.js could be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

```js
var origDateFormat = "2017-03-23";
var expectedDateFormat = "3/23/2017";
var newDateFormat = moment(origDateFormat).format('M/DD/YYYY');
console.log(newDateFormat===expectedDateFormat); //true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is no library tag or mention in the OP, so your answer should not rely on one.

Comment: How is OP going to mention or tag something he doesn't know exists?

Comment: It's fine to mention a library as an alternative, but it's not reasonable to answer only with a library. Otherwise there may be many answers differentiated only by the library used (and there are many date parsing and formatting libraries).